# Replace all words ending with n't in a data-frame in R

Tags: r

I am looking for a solution which can replace all words ending with n't to 2 parts like "hasn't" to "has not" or "wasn't" to "was not".

Right now I have the below solution but I will have to do it for all words so wanted to know that can be done in one line:

```
levels(txt$Comments)<-gsub("haven't", "have not",levels(txt$Comments))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make use of a regular expression (see `help("regex")`):

```
x <- c("has", "hasn't", "was", "wasn't")
sub("n't$", " not", x)

# [1] "has"     "has not" "was"     "was not"
```

Here we take advantage of the `$` special regex character, which stands for the end of the string. So, every element that *ends* in `"n't"` will have the `"n't"` replaced with `" not"`. This will work if all of the elements of `x` are one word. However, if you have at least some that are multiple words, you should use `\\b`, the empty string marking the edge of a word:

```
x <- c("has", "hasn't done anything", "was", "wasn't")
sub("n't\\b", " not", x)

# [1] "has"                   "has not done anything" "was"                  
# [4] "was not"
```

Moreover, if there could potentially be multiple such words in one element of your vector, you need `gsub()` rather than `sub()`:

```
x <- c("has", "hasn't", "was", "I wasn't available, so we couldn't meet")
sub("n't\\b", " not", x)

# [1] "has"                                     
# [2] "has not"                                 
# [3] "was"                                     
# [4] "I was not available, so we couldn't meet"

gsub("n't\\b", " not", x)

# [1] "has"                                      
# [2] "has not"                                  
# [3] "was"                                      
# [4] "I was not available, so we could not meet"
```

#### The problem of "can't"

As pointed out in the comments, if the word `"can't"` might appear in your data, you'll need to first change all instances of it to `"cann't"` or else you'll end up with `"ca not"`:

```
x <- "I am not available, so we can't meet"
gsub("n't\\b", " not", x)

# [1] "I am not available, so we ca not meet"

x <- gsub("can't", "cann't", x)
gsub("n't\\b", " not", x)

# [1] "I am not available, so we can not meet"
```

Comment: Thank you this works great. I end up with one small problem of can't which breaks it "ca not". Might be first I will replace all can't with "cann't" and later run the replace. My text are all comments so mix of multiple words.

Comment: @ShuhomChoudhury Good point, and that should be a good work around; I'll add that into the answer for any future viewers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one using regular expression `grouping ()`

```
gsub("(.*)(n\\'t)","\\1 not","haven't")
[1] "have not"
```